# Firebase relational delete

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say i have 4 firebase collections.

**Categories -> SubCategories -> Items and FavoriteItems**

with this data

**Category:**

- Category Name

**Subcategory:**

- Subcategory name, CategoryID

**Item:**

- Item Name, SubcategoryID

**FavoriteItems:**

- UserID
- ItemIdArray

I want to be able to delete a category, but while doing so deleting all the subcategories and items and favorites depending on that category document.

What is the best approach for doing this?

- Should I add all the categories and subcategories as information on the Items, and then delete them.
- Is there a way to do this in a database rule, or stored function?
- Or how should i model my data?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad, but I can suggest something. There is possibility to create [Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) based on `onDelete` [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

Using this feature you can run practically every logic that is triggered by delete event in Firestore. I can imagine that you can even create "nested" solution putting triggers on every item. So deleting of collection item, can trigger function that will delete subcategory. Deleting subcategory will trigger another function that will delete Items... and so on and so forth...

This is of course one of many solution we can thing of... NoSql databases, like Firestore, do not have schema and they give practically unlimited number of possible data structures.